# Mocking with Dart

Tags: mocking, dart, dart-unittest, dart-mock

I've been trying to get my head around the mocking library in dart, but it seems I've still not got it.

In my library, I have an HTTP request to an external resource, which I would like to mock as to not rely on the external resource all the time.

The main class in my library looks like this:

```dart
SampleClass(String arg1, String arg2, [http.Client httpClient = null]) {
    this._arg1 = arg1;
    this._arg2 = arg2;
    _httpClient = (httpClient == null) ? http.Request : httpClient;
}
```

So I have prepared my class to receive http.client as an argument, as this is what I would like to mock.

So in my unit tests file I've created:

```dart
class HttpClientMock extends Mock implements http.Client {
  noSuchMethod(i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);
}
```

And on my unit test I have done:

```dart
var mockHttpClient = new HttpClientMock()
        ..when(callsTo('send')).alwaysReturn("this is a test");
```

I would then expect that every time I called "send" from my library, which has been instanciated in my unit tests with the optional "httpClient", that it would return "this is a test". I'm pretty sure I'm missing somethign very big here, but can't quite put my finger on what.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are missing because your example works for me:

```dart
void main() {
  test('bla', () {
    var mockHttpClient = new HttpClientMock()
            ..when(callsTo('send')).alwaysReturn("this is a test");

    http.Request req = new http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://www.google.com'));
    var s = mockHttpClient.send(req);
    print(s);
    expect(mockHttpClient.send(req), equals('this is a test'));

  });
}
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks again. I was stuck in a different problem and though there was a problem with what I was doing. I will post another question with the real problem I'm stuck with :-)