# Mocking HTTP response with Dart

Tags: mocking, dart, dart-unittest, dart-mock

I have been working on a new API wrapper and don't want to be calling the API every time my unit tests run. So as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208588/mocking-with-dart), I'm mocking it.

I initially thought there was something wrong with the way I'm mocking it, but it seems the problem is elsewhere.

What I'm trying to accomplish is very simple. When my unit test run, I would like to return a value as if I had gone out to get the information from the external API I'm integrating with.

I initialise my class with http.Client as an optional parameter, so I can pass it in when the unit tests run as such:

```dart
SampleClass(String arg1, String arg2, [http.Client httpClient = null]) {
    this._arg1 = arg1;
    this._arg2 = arg2;
    _httpClient = (httpClient == null) ? http.Request : httpClient;
}

Future apiRequest(String resource, [Map<String, String> body]) {
    var url = buildBaseUrl(resource).toString();
    var request = new http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(url));
    request.bodyFields = body;
    return this._httpClient.send(request).then((response) => response.stream.bytesToString().then((value) => value.toString()));
}
```

In my unit test I have created the following mock class:

```dart
class HttpClientMock extends Mock implements http.Client {
  noSuchMethod(i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);
}

class HttpResponseMock extends Mock implements http.Response {
    noSuchMethod(i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);
}
```

And in my unit test to check the response I'm doing the following:

```dart
test("Send SMS errors with wrong account", () {
    var mockHttpClient = new HttpClientMock()
                             ..when(callsTo('send')).alwaysReturn(message401);
    var sample = new SampleClass(_arg1, _arg2, mockHttpClient);
    future = sample.apiRequest(...parameters here...).then((value) => value.toString());
    expect(future.then((value) => JSON.decode(value)), completion(equals(JSON.decode(message401))));
});
```

So, as you can see, I am trying to make it so calling send returns `message401`, which is just a `JSON` string.

This is not happening, since `message401` is a string, and because my code tries to use it as a Future, I always get the error:

> Top-level uncaught error: Class 'String' has no instance method
>   'then'.

I totally understand why I'm getting this error, but have no idea about how to go around it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `http` package has a [testing library](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/http.testing-library.html) with a [MockClient](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) already implemented for you.

Comment: Can you guys post an example using MockClient please

Comment: @Frank The link in the answer has an example

Answer (score 2):

Try

```dart
.alwaysReturn(new Future.value(message401));
```

Comment: Your example absolutely worked, but I have marked Sean's answer as the correct one, since it offers a "native" way of accomplishing this. thank you so much though!

Answer (score 2):

There is the [nock](https://pub.dev/packages/nock) package for that:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:nock/nock.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    nock.init();
  });

  setUp(() {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  test("example", () async {
    final interceptor = nock("http://localhost/api").get("/users")
      ..reply(
        200,
        "result",
      );

    final response = await http.get("http://localhost/api/users");

    expect(interceptor.isDone, true);
    expect(response.statusCode, 200);
    expect(response.body, "result");
  });
}
```

It uses HttpOverrides, so you don't need to inject MockClient. Works both with `dio` and `http` packages.

Comment: Okay, but I have a problem with it. I'm trying to create several interceptors (because I have several requests) but only 1 works ...

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example from the included [tests for MockClient](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/test/mock_client_test.dart) in the `http` package you can get from pub.dev

Add the `http` [package to your pubspec.yaml file](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install)...

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.2
```

In your unit test dart file...

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {

  test('handles a request', () async {
    var client = MockClient((request) async {
      return Response(json.encode(request.bodyFields), 200, request: request);
    }
    );

    var response = await client.post('http://example.com/foo', body: {'field1': 'value1'});

    expect(response.body, contains('value1'));
  });
}
```